# How to open play store app direclty from android app and search a package

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

Is there any way to open Google Play store app directly from my app and search a package that I need to pass from my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
startActivity(launchIntent);
```